# Node.js express and net socket using 1 single port

Tags: node.js, express, port

So I roughly have this setup:

```
const net = require('net');
const express = require('express');

const socketsHostPort = 8082;
const websiteHostPort = process.env.PORT

const app = express();
app.get(/* Setup stuff etc */)
// A lot of app setup stuff here of course
app.listen(websiteHostPort);

let socket_server = net.createServer(/* Do stuff with the sockets */);
socket_server.listen(hostPort, 192.168.0.101);
```

Now I actually want to host it somewhere of course, but the problem is that it uses 2 separate ports (8082 and a port given by the environment as can be seen in the code).

The place I want to host this only gives me a single port (the one given by process.env.PORT) but I have things running on these 2 ports.

Can i use express somehow (or a different way) to make both of these run only one the one port? Maybe a specific path can be used for the Node.js net sockets?

I'm relatively new to express and Node.js in general, but I could not find anything about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port sharing among two protocols is possible with specific design or with some serious hacking.  An example of specific design is the webSocket protocol.  It is specifically designed to be able to share a port with an http server.  They do that by initiating every webSocket connection with an http request that has a few custom headers set.  The http server or a request handler in the http server can identify those specific headers and can then shunt the code off to the webSocket handling code where both ends can then agree to change the protocol they speak to the webSocket protocol instead of the http protocol.

Without such a specific sharing design, it is a lot harder.  You would have to have a generic TCP server that accepts the incoming connection and then examines the first set of data that arrives and determines whether that data looks like it belongs to an http request (in which case it passed the socket off to be handled by http server logic) or whether the data looks like whatever protocol you're running on the TCP socket.

A plain TCP connection has no path associated with it.  That's part of an http request so you would have to do something like the webSocket design where all your connection requests start with an actual http request if you wanted to use the request path to differentiate and at that point, you can also use custom headers on the request too.

In fact, you might just examine whether you can use a webSocket connection instead of your TCP connection since it already has this port sharing capability built-in.